# pgfplotstable -> Create columns of ALL string type

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am importing data from a text file that has about a dozen columns. Most, if not all, are string fields. The exception to the rule is the odd float column. In order for this to render, end up having to do something like:

```
display columns/0/.style={string type},                      
display columns/1/.style={string type}
```

The problem is, I end up needing to do this several times.

Is there a way to apply this to ALL columns, and only override the exceptions?

Thanks!

Comment: Can’t you just use the ‘string type’ key? See the example on p 17 of the manual.

Comment: Thanks, @Schrödinger'scat. That did the trick. I didn't know what I was looking for in the example.

Answer (score 1):

To make this change happen for all columns, I added it like:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, string type, ...
```

The change was then applied to all columns.

You can find the example on page 17 of the manual.